# Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 142ms (Views: 9.8ms | ActiveRecord: 34.6ms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application that allows users to create events and activities and others can view them (in the show page) and attend if they'd like.

Now the thing is, I'm able to click on an Event and the event#show page pops up and everything is great, incidentally the Activity page doesn't open, I get a 404 error.

When checking the heroku logs, and the development console logs in development I don't see any visible errors, the only error I see is:

```
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 142ms (Views: 9.8ms | ActiveRecord: 34.6ms)
```

What could this be? I've looked over the code several times and there aren't any obvious problems, and also it works in development I only get this 404 in production.. Any ideas?

Update: Heroku logs:

```
2014-04-07T17:08:57.651579+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
2014-04-07T17:08:57.651738+00:00 app[web.1]: Geokit is using the domain: *hidden*
2014-04-07T17:08:57.657087+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY random() LIMIT 5
2014-04-07T17:08:57.663588+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (4.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 40 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-04-07T17:08:57.672547+00:00 app[web.1]:   Activity Load (7.7ms)  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.676877+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 38]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.693696+00:00 app[web.1]:   Photo Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 40], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.697251+00:00 app[web.1]:   Ethnicity Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "ethnicities".* FROM "ethnicities" WHERE "ethnicities"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "ethnicities"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.699600+00:00 app[web.1]:   Education Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "educations".* FROM "educations" WHERE "educations"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "educations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.710452+00:00 app[web.1]:   Question Load (9.6ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 40]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.712549+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM 
"photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 40], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.728908+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (15.5ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 40], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.730101+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 40], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.730981+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 40], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.761039+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_left_side.html.erb (72.0ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.731304+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_profile_completion.html.erb (19.6ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.760362+00:00 app[web.1]:   Message Exists (3.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "messages"."is_new" = 't' LIMIT 1  [["recipient_id", 40]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.786347+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 40], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.782607+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2  [["commentable_id", 4], ["commentable_type", "Activity"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.799144+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 40], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.818837+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered collection (0.0ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.833708+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Exists (5.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" INNER JOIN "activity_participants" ON "users"."id" = "activity_participants"."user_id" WHERE "activity_participants"."activity_id" = $1 AND "users"."id" = 40 LIMIT 1  [["activity_id", 4]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.840280+00:00 app[web.1]:   Photo Load (3.9ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 38], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.818561+00:00 app[web.1]:   Comment Load (5.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2 AND "comments"."parent_id" IS NULL  [["commentable_id", 4], ["commentable_type", "Activity"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.841447+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 38], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.858143+00:00 app[web.1]:    (5.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "activity_participants" ON "users"."id" = "activity_participants"."user_id" WHERE "activity_participants"."activity_id" = $1  [["activity_id", 4]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.863920+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 38], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.861996+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "activity_participants" ON "users"."id" = "activity_participants"."user_id" WHERE "activity_participants"."activity_id" = $1  [["activity_id", 4]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.864761+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2 AND "photos"."profile_photo" = 't' ORDER BY "photos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["attachable_id", 38], ["attachable_type", "User"]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.869745+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered activities/_activity_right_side.html.erb (45.4ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.869976+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered activities/show.html.erb within layouts/application (184.0ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.871758+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered errors/error_500.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.875144+00:00 app[web.1]:   Event Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "event_participants" ON "events"."id" = "event_participants"."event_id" WHERE "event_participants"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 40]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.875788+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_pusher.html.erb (3.1ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.880542+00:00 app[web.1]:   Notification Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND "notifications"."is_opened" = 'f' LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 40]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.882166+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND "notifications"."is_opened" = 'f' LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 40]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.891660+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/activities/4 host=*hidden* request_id=f6f6ab0e-c627-482d-a49b-d7d351ba398a fwd="99.234.25.253" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=393ms status=500 bytes=10914
2014-04-07T17:08:57.884160+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "messages"."is_new" = 't' LIMIT 1  [["recipient_id", 40]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.883375+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "messages"."is_new" = 't' LIMIT 1  [["recipient_id", 40]]
2014-04-07T17:08:57.884773+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (8.2ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.885126+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.885902+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 234ms (Views: 12.7ms | ActiveRecord: 81.1ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:57.885600+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2014-04-07T17:08:58.357410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/logo-404-6d97dc33614d27e176e8344ea679813f.png host=www.friendiose.com request_id=d00190ed-d365-46aa-978d-53c0fed636f4 fwd="99.234.25.253" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=30821
2014-04-07T17:09:04.078418+00:00 heroku[run.8642]: State changed from up to complete
2014-04-07T17:09:04.066492+00:00 heroku[run.8642]: Process exited with status 0
2014-04-07T17:08:56.083949+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/place_map_icon-eea0b812cae352793b07d4cc9ab29ab6.png host=www.friendiose.com request_id=288b92d3-46fc-4d3c-a6c2-edcb1746aa7b fwd="99.234.25.253" dyno=web.1 connect=15ms service=37ms status=200 bytes=3282
2014-04-07T17:08:55.818610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/w_icon-b05939cd15957a224c909f4152f6de76.png host=www.friendiose.com request_id=8558679d-8b23-424a-b285-0a5756d637c9 fwd="99.234.25.253" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=89
2014-04-07T17:10:45.276715+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-04-07T17:10:45.276355 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/activities/4" for 99.234.25.253 at 2014-04-07 17:10:45 +0000
2014-04-07T17:10:45.276873+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-04-07T17:10:45.276522 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/activities/4" for 99.234.25.253 at 2014-04-07 17:10:45 +0000
```

Comment: Can you show us the `heroku logs` ?

Comment: Cheers! Sure, I've updated the original post with them. Thanks

Comment: @user3399101 did find solution to this error